# Flex mxmlc ant task gives java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: apache-flex, build, ant, mxmlc

I'm getting this error while trying to build flex project

```
 [mxmlc] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.NodeFactory.expressionStatement(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.NodeFactory.expressionStatement(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.semantics.FlowAnalyzer.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.FunctionDefinitionNode.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.semantics.FlowAnalyzer.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.ClassDefinitionNode.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.semantics.FlowAnalyzer.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.ArgumentListNode.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.semantics.FlowAnalyzer.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.SetExpressionNode.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.semantics.FlowAnalyzer.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.MemberExpressionNode.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.semantics.FlowAnalyzer.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.ExpressionStatementNode.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.semantics.FlowAnalyzer.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.ClassDefinitionNode.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.semantics.FlowAnalyzer.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.ProgramNode.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.as3.Compiler.analyze2(Compiler.java:466)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.ImplementationCompiler.analyze2(ImplementationCompiler.java:249)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.Compiler.analyze2(Compiler.java:141)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.API.analyze(API.java:2523)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.API.analyze(API.java:2423)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.API.batch2(API.java:386)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.API.batch(API.java:1108)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.API.compile(API.java:1281)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.API.compile(API.java:1201)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.tools.Compiler.mxmlc(Compiler.java:240)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.tools.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:53)
```

I don't have the admin access to my Desktop , so I am figuring out a way to run the build xml without setting ANT_OPTS system variable.

I have tried setting  _JAVA_OPTIONS upto 2 GB but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using x86 or x64 system?

Comment: @ProgrammerDancuk x64 system